# Raspbian Chromium Startup

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, chromium

I am setting up a "kiosk" mode display but Im having a hard time getting chromium to show properly on raspbian login.  If I comment the line out, and manually start chromium, it will show.  If I start using various different startup arguments in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`  chromium starts but no window shows.  How do I know?  `ps aux | grep chromium` shows it's started up.  If I try to open a browser after that, it will just say "opening in existing browser session" which is obviously also a problem because the existing browser session isn't showing.

I am *guessing* that it has something to do with the "restore pages" dialogue box, because if I start chromium manually, without any autostart scripts, it will ask me if i want to restore pages.  But, I'd assumed `--disable-restore-session-state` flag would have taken care of that.  [I did find another threat](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68734/how-do-i-disable-restore-pages-chromium-didnt-shut-down-correctly-prompt) that mentioned I should flag the opening address with --app but that also didn't work.  Here are variations of what I've tried in my autostart script...

```
@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-restore-session-state -http://127.0.0.1
@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-restore-session-state ---app=http://127.0.0.1
@chromium-browser --kiosk --app=http://127.0.0.1
@chromium-browser --kiosk http://127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@chromium-browser --kiosk --force-device-scale-factor=2.0 --user-data-dir=/home/pi/.config/chromium-display1 --app=https://[first site]
@chromium-browser --kiosk --force-device-scale-factor=1.0 --user-data-dir=/home/pi/.config/chromium-display2 --window-position=1921,0 --app=https://[second site]
```

works for me. I am using it for two different displays so you can remove the second one if you don't need it.

Comment: That's essentially the same as what I'd already done `@chromium-browser --kiosk --app=http://127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by adding the `--app-auto-launched` flag to one of my previously mentioned entries.

```
@chromium-browser --kiosk --app-auto-launched --app=http://127.0.0.1
```

Reference link: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#app-auto-launched